# Designing a self-rotating generic list

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure similar to a `List<T>`.

What I want to be able to do is specify the maximum number of items this structure can hold, for example, 10 items. When an 11th item is added, what I want it to do is remove the first item added, move the rest of the items up in the list and add the 11th item to the bottom of the list.

When another item is added, again, the top item is removed and everything moves up again, etc etc.

Is there a data structure like this already that exists in .NET? Or do I need to build my own?

Comment: Any reason why the `Stack` datatype isn't acceptable?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `LinkedList<T>`

Comment: @JeremyThompson It doesn't automatically behave like a circular list, although it's a good candidate for the underlying data structure

Comment: @JeremyThompson - Because with a `Stack`, the data "pops" out. I want the data to stay in the table. In addition, a Stack pop will always return the last entry. I may not want that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Queue<T>` would be the closest.  It would be easy to wrap a `Queue<T>` in another class to implement the auto-dequeueing of the head once the queue was the maximum size.

Comment: @Andrew -- I thought of that, but the problem with a queue is that when I dequeue the data, it removes the data from the list completely. I want the data to stay in the list when I pull it. Also, with a queue, isn't always just the first item on the queue that I have access to?

Comment: You can iterate over the queue as an IEnumerable<T> without dequeuing the items.

Comment: @AndrewCooper -- Can I use LINQ on a Queue? If so, then a `Queue<T>` will work for what I need!

Comment: The only real catch I can see is that you can't access the elements of the queue by index.

Comment: Absolutely.  `Queue<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so anything goes.

Comment: I don't really need to access by index, as long as I can use LINQ to pull a specific data item

Comment: Awesome! This will fulfill my requirements! Thanks for all the input!